# How to disable fragment scroll in horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recyclerView that I populate with imageViews, so that when the user swipes from right to left, the rest of the images appear one by one. Everything is behaving correctly, images are loaded and horizontal scroll works as expected, even the clickListeners for individual items work fine...

**BUT**... if the touch gesture to scroll to the right is not a **pure horizontal swipe** (or left if the user reaches the end of the recyclerView and wants to go back), the fragment where the recyclerView is being loaded **scrolls down, too**. I want to avoid this behavior, so that when the user intends to reach the images swipping from right to left, the **recyclerView only moves in the horizontal direction, ignoring any vertical movement** that is performed over the recyclerView. If the user taps or swipes outside of the recyclerView screen area, I want usual behavior to occur (scroll down as expected). I have tried with other alternatives seen in this site, like using the **setOnTouchListener** option to detect a MotionEvent and act accordingly, as you can check below (this is actual code from my fragment):

```
advertPicturesRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener { recyclerView, motionEvent ->
        when(motionEvent.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Touch down!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                recyclerView.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                true
            }
            else -> {
                recyclerView.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                true
            }
        }
    }
```

In this context, ACTION_UP means in the direction of the recyclerView, so this just detects movement inside the recyclerView and sort of "passes" vertical movement to the parent (fragment), which scrolls down.

**How can I "block" the recyclerView to ignore any vertical swipe**, and only move horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
myRecylcerView?.layoutManager = viewManager
```

The above snippet will allow only a horizontal scroll based on your question but I guess there is something else that is causing the problem like you might be using a NestedScrollView/ScrollView, so please provide the layout files and a sample video to have a clear perspective of the problem.

**Update - 25th September 2020**

You can try the below to your NestedScrollView and recylcerview

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nsvMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never">
    // .....
    // .....

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
```

```java
myRecylcerView?.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

It would be much better if you attach your layout file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Harsh Rajgor. You are right, the problem is coming from a NestedScrollView which is part of the layout. The ReclyclerView is inside the NestedScrollView, and when I put it outside of the NestedScrollLayout it works as expected, but now it always takes a fixed screen space to show the RecyclerView, which is not desirable for design reasons. Would it be possible to disable the scroll of the NestedScrollView over the RecyclerView only? (i.e., I want the NestedScrollView to ignore down swipes when those are performed over the horizontal RecyclerView)

Comment: @Franbede, I have updated the answer, and also please attach the layout file if the updated solution isn't able to solve your problem.